# Como calcular tamanho de uma div header para fazer o espacamento correto?

Tags: html, css

Olá,

Tenho um site com um menu fixed no topo o qual coloquei a classe header, e ele acompanha a barra de rolagem, sei que minha outra div com a classe content precisa de um margin de acordo com a altura do header para nao ficar tampado. Minha duvida é como eu faço isso de forma flexivel. Que independente da altura do header o margin da div contain seja alterado sem eu precisar mudar o margin toda hora.

```css
html {
  background-color: #bcbcbc;
}

.header {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

.header h2{
     text-align: center;
}

.content{
  height: 100%;
  
}
.footer {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<div class="header"> 
  <h2>FIXED</h2>
</div>
  
<div class="content"> 
  <h1>Conteudo</h1>
  <h1>Conteudo</h1>
  <h1>Conteudo</h1>
  <h1>Conteudo</h1>
  <h1>Conteudo</h1>
  <h1>Conteudo</h1>

</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc pode substituir o `position:fixed` por `position:sticky` vc pode ler mais sobre aqui: https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/

Conforme o Jorge falou no comentário segundo o site *Can I Use* essa propriedade não funciona no IE  https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky Mas tenha em mente que o Windows 10 que é o atual o browser padrão é o Edge não o IE, e que daqui para frente o IE só tende a sumir, e pode ser que nem venha mais nas próximas versões do Windows...

Veja como fica o resultado, coloquei uma transparência no topo só para vc ver que não tem nada por baixo...

```css
html {
    background-color: #bcbcbc;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.header {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    height: 100px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: sticky;
}

.header h2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}

.content {
    height: 100%;

}

.footer {
    background-color: black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <h2>FIXED</h2>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <h1>Conteudo</h1>
    <h1>Conteudo</h1>
    <h1>Conteudo</h1>
    <h1>Conteudo</h1>
    <h1>Conteudo</h1>
    <h1>Conteudo</h1>

</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
```

Comment: Vale lembrar que  `position:sticky` só tem suporte em navagadores mais modernos, IE por exemplo não suporta. Seria legal colocar a referência para consultas futuras: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Comment: @Jorge.M sem problemas fiz a observação na resposta.